# RT3592BC8 Bluetooth and FreeBSD

Tags: wifi, freebsd, bluetooth

Several years ago (in 2008) I purchased a HP ProBook which I now want to sell because I got a newer laptop in January 2016. The ProBook is a Celeron Dual Core with 4GB of RAM and 250GB HDD. I have two potential buyers, one who wants it for his office to replace an older barely functioning Pentium3 laptop and the other who wants it as a FreeBSD workstation.

The former buyer will pay me $400 and the latter one $650 but the latter one wants full compatibility with FreeBSD (or if push comes to shove, something like Slackware or Arch Linux) and a fast and strong WiFi with Bluetooth since he will be doing a lot of heavy Internet usage from many different locations with no access to wired Ethernet (like WiFi in restaurants) and has a mobile phone which he needs to sync through Bluetooth. He doesn't want dongles so Bluetooth must be internal.

Using an Intel 6230 or 6235 (both great, powerful WiFi+Bluetooth cards) is not an option since the PC has a BIOS WiFi whitelist which causes it to halt at BIOS POST with this error message if I install any card not included in the whitelist:[image]

Modding the BIOS to remove the whitelist is impossible in this model because the BIOS is RSA signed and uses a non-standard size and format (all this proprietariness was one of the reasons I got myself a new, more hacker friendly laptop)

The whitelist contains the following cards:

1. Realtek 8188CEB8
2. BroadCom 4313
3. Atheros 9485
4. Atheros 9280
5. Ralink 3592BC8
6. Intel 1030

The first three and the last ones are single band, single stream which makes them quite weak for his purposes, the first two are also incompatible with FreeBSD.  The fourth and fifth ones are dual band and dual stream, very powerful cards, but the fourth one lacks bluetooth capacity and the fifth one is a potential candidate, but is pretty expensive and I want to know before ordering if it's going to work the way he expects.

To assess these possibilities, I would like to ask if anyone who has one of those cards could post the output of `lsusb -v` to see if the Bluetooth module has suitable features (wikidevi doesn't list the features of the Bluetooth module built into combo cards) and if it works in FreeBSD or not.
I ask this because I need to know, before I spend money in a RT3592BC8, if it will allow me to make this ProBook meet the requirements of this prospective buyer who is willing to pay me $650.